# Extensibility point on release results page

Tags: azure-devops

I am part of VS performance team, I need to create a new tab for the Release result page.[Release result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3OW3.png)

Previously it was possible with the target ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-details-view but that no longer works on the new experience, do you know how the contribution configuration should look?, this is what I have so far:

```
         "id": "pit-tab",
        "type": "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-summary-tab",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-details-view"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Performance",
            "uri": "dist/index.html",
            "order": "99",
            "icon": "asset://img/icon.png",
            "supportsMobile": true
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below script:

```
{
  "id": "release-environments-tab",
  "type": "ms.vss-web.tab",
  "description": "Adds a 'Merlin Insert' tab to the release environment.",
  "targets": [
    "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-environment-editor-tab"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "Merlin Insert",
    "order": "30",
    "uri": "index.html"
  }
},
```

[image]